# How to export image in excel file from mysql database dynamically

Tags: phpexcel

I want to export image from mysql database into an excel file using phpexcel.I have done it with static value but can not do it dynamically.

```
    <?php
include ('config.php');

function my_constants(){
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/phpexcel_gd/";
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/phpexcel_gd/';
    define('SITEURL', $url);
    define('SITEPATH', str_replace('\\', '/', $path));
}

function report_details($display = null) {

    if($display){
        $imagePath = SITEURL . "images/";
    } else {
        $imagePath = SITEPATH . "images/";
    }   

    // $select_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT orderid, image_name,image_path FROM tbl_order_details WHERE orderid = '240419-0001-A1-B1'");
    // $select_query_row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query);

    // $orderid = $select_query['orderid'];
    // $image_name= $select_query['image_name'];
    // $image_path = $select_query['image_path'];

    $reportdetails = array(
        // array('Image' => $image_path . $image_name,'orderid' => $orderid),
        array('BrandIcon' => $imagePath . "github.png",'Comapany' => "Github",'Rank' => "3",'Link' => "https://github.com/"),
        array('BrandIcon' => $imagePath . "bootstrap.png",'Comapany' => "Bootstrap",'Rank' => "4",'Link' => "http://getbootstrap.com/"),
        array('BrandIcon' => $imagePath . "so-icon.png",'Comapany' => "Stack Overflow",'Rank' => "3",'Link' => "http://stackoverflow.com/"),
    );
    return $reportdetails;

}

/**
* Create excel by from ajax request
*/
function xlscreation_ajax() {

    $reportdetails = report_details();

    require_once SITEPATH . 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()
            ->setCreator("user")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("user")
            ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
            ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
            ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
            ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
            ->setCategory("Test result file");

    // Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 

    // Initialise the Excel row number
    $rowCount = 0; 

    // Sheet cells
    $cell_definition = array(
        'A' => 'BrandIcon',
        'B' => 'Company',
        'C' => 'Rank',
        'D' => 'Link'
    );

    // Build headers
    foreach( $cell_definition as $column => $value )
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("{$column}")->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( "{$column}1", $value ); 
    }

    // Build cells
    while( $rowCount < count($reportdetails) ){ 
        $cell = $rowCount + 2;
        foreach( $cell_definition as $column => $value ) {

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($rowCount + 2)->setRowHeight(35); 

            switch ($value) {
                case 'BrandIcon':
                    if (file_exists($reportdetails[$rowCount][$value])) {
                        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
                        $objDrawing->setName('Customer Signature');
                        $objDrawing->setDescription('Customer Signature');
                        //Path to signature .jpg file
                        $signature = $reportdetails[$rowCount][$value];    
                        $objDrawing->setPath($signature);
                        $objDrawing->setOffsetX(25);                     //setOffsetX works properly
                        $objDrawing->setOffsetY(10);                     //setOffsetY works properly
                        $objDrawing->setCoordinates($column.$cell);             //set image to cell 
                        $objDrawing->setWidth(32);  
                        $objDrawing->setHeight(32);                     //signature height  
                        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());  //save 
                    } else {
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$cell, "Image not found" ); 
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Link':
                    //set the value of the cell
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column.$cell, $reportdetails[$rowCount][$value]);
                    //change the data type of the cell
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column.$cell)->setDataType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING2);
                    ///now set the link
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column.$cell)->getHyperlink()->setUrl(strip_tags($reportdetails[$rowCount][$value]));
                    break;

                default:
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$cell, $reportdetails[$rowCount][$value] ); 
                    break;
            }

        }

        $rowCount++; 
    } 

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $saveExcelToLocalFile = saveExcelToLocalFile($objWriter);
    $response = array(
         'success' => true,
         'filename' => $saveExcelToLocalFile['filename'],
         'url' => $saveExcelToLocalFile['filePath']
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}

function saveExcelToLocalFile($objWriter) {

    $rand = rand(1234, 9898);
    $presentDate = date('YmdHis');
    $fileName = "report_" . $rand . "_" . $presentDate . ".xlsx";

    // make sure you have permission to write to directory
    $filePath = SITEPATH . 'reports/' . $fileName;
    $objWriter->save($filePath);
    $data = array(
        'filename' => $fileName,
        'filePath' => $filePath
    );
    return $data;

}

?>
```

Here the $reportdetails contains the static array. How can I pass the mysql database value to the array dynamically? Please suggest any alternative other than phpexcel.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried that reads the information from your database that isn't working correctly.

Comment: I have used a static array. I want to know how to get the data from a Mysql Database with image.